# I am not able to call the Apex variable in my visualforce page how can I fix?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, pdf

So I have a lightning component that will open a visualforce page when you click the pdf button. The visualforce page opens in pdf format but I can't call the Apex variable to get the Account Name, Type etc. For simplicity I've only posted the relevant code. How can I call the apex variable to display account fields on the vfp page?

[image]
Aura:

```
<aura:attribute name="searchResult" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchString" type="String"/>     
<aura:attribute name="Message" type="boolean" default="false"/>     
<aura:attribute name="id" type="object"/>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.searchResult}" var="account">
    <tr>
        <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!account.Name}">{!account.Name}</div></td>
        <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!account.Type}">{!account.Type}</div></td>
        <td>    

      <!-- Use a Lightning Base Component To display an icon next to the label -->

          <lightning:button
            label="PDF"
            iconName="utility:open"
            iconPosition="left"
            variant="base"
            type="submit"
            onclick="{!c.downloadPDF}"
            value="{!account.Id}" 
             />
       </td>
   </tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

Controller:

```
 downloadPDF : function (component, event, helper)
    {
        //get acc id from pdf button
        var myId = event.getSource().get('v.value'); 
        //call apex controller
        var action = component.get("c.DisplayAccounts");
        //set variable equal to acc id
        action.setParams({'pdfSearch': myId});
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                alert(myId);            
                window.open('/apex/AccountPDFViewer?id=' + myId);


            }
            else{
                console.log('unable to generate the pdf');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    },
```

Apex:

```
public class AccountPDFController
{   
    public String PDFData {get;set;}
    public static Account acc{get;set;}

    public AccountPDFController()
    {
        PDFData='';
        acc = new Account();
    }
   @AuraEnabled  
    public static Account DisplayAccounts(String pdfSearch)
    {
        system.debug(pdfSearch);
        String secondSearch = pdfSearch;
        List < Account > pdfList = [SELECT Id, name, Type FROM Account Where Id=:secondSearch];
        system.debug('Apex Step 4');
        acc = pdfList[0];
        system.debug('Apex step 5');
        return acc;

    }
}
```

VFP:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountPDFController" renderas="PDF">
    <apex:outputText value="{!acc.Name}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `standardController` in apex page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountPDFController " >
    name - {!Account.Name}
</apex:page>
```

You dont need any declaration of extra variable like `acc`. Standard controller `Account` itself acts as accessor. You extension controller should constructor with standard controller parameter:

```
public class AccountPDFController {

    public AccountPDFController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){}

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect, why does it not work the other way?

Comment: It will work if you query the account in constructor by getting the Id parameter from url. Much more complex than using standard controller.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the help! I still have much to learn

Comment: Is there anyway I could pm you? I have another question about querying from constructor. I actually just ran into another project with that as a use case

Comment: not sure how `pm` works in SFSE. I am actually new to this platform. However I answered your question :)